How can I generate markup for dynamic content in a React Native app?
I’m building a React Native app with dynamic content, and I want to ensure the app generates SEO-friendly markup for search engines. Given that React Native does not natively support server-side rendering, I am investigating methods to optimize the app for crawlers with limited JavaScript support.
I’ve Tried

Static Markup with Rendertron:
I used Rendertron to pre-render pages for search engine crawlers. While it works, it adds complexity to the deployment process, and I’m struggling to dynamically update metadata for each page.

Meta Tags and Open Graph:
I implemented meta tags and Open Graph tags, but I suspect they’re not sufficient for search engines that don’t fully render JavaScript content.

Exploring Alternatives to SSR:
I’ve read about alternatives like pre-rendering static content during build time but couldn’t find a clear approach tailored for React Native apps.


My Questions

How can I generate SEO-friendly static or pre-rendered markup for a React Native app with dynamic content?

Are there any tools or libraries specifically designed for SEO optimization in React Native apps?

What’s the best way to handle dynamic metadata updates for SEO purposes?


